# How can i use DateTime field in model without second ,only date

Tags: python, django

I am creating a model that has a DateTime field. I want to store only date without seconds and hour. How can i do that?

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    d_value=models.IntegerField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(UserSignupModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `DateField`:

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    d_value=models.IntegerField()
    created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(UserSignupModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```